# 3.3V to 5V PWM level shift

Tags: pwm, esp32, voltage-level, drone

I need to shift a PWM signal from a ESP32 (3.3V) to receiver that supports 5V. The signal is at maximum of 400Hz. Can this shifter do the job ? [image: SparkFun shifter]

Comment: Yes, it can. Though depending on the receiver you may not need it. If the receiver is a 5V Arduino, it will see 3.3V on its digital input pin as HIGH.

Comment: Already bought it and it works, and no, the receiver is not an Arduino, it's an ESC (Electronic speed controller) for a quadcopter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work, but it's overkill. Those devices are made for bidirectional signaling. You should be able to use a single transistor that is driven to saturation at 3.3V. A Suitable "logic level" MOSFET with a 3.3 gate voltage should do the trick.

And, as Chris L said in his answer, you may be able to drive an input on a 5V Arduino directly with 3.3V. That's a high enough voltage to be read as a logic level 1.